# How to pytest monkeypatch a mixin class in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I need to monkeypatch a mixin class inherited by other classes using pytest, python 3.x, I have this example:

```
class A:
  @classmethod
  def foo(cls) -> str:
    # do some database operation
    return "foo"

class B(A):
  pass
```

I initially thought of monkeypatching the method directly by doing something like this:

```
def test_B(monkeypatch):
  def mock_b__foo() -> str:
    return 'bar'
  monkeypatch.setattr('B.foo', mock_b__foo)
```

Then I tried this:

```
def test_B(monkeypatch):
  class MockA:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls) -> str:
      # do some database operation
      return "bar"

  monkeypatch.setattr('A', MockA)
```

This does not work as intended, B.foo still inherits from A instead of MockA because the import is evaluated once I guess, any way of achieving this ?

Comment: `foo` is not a function; it's an instance of `classmethod` that *wraps* a function. Try `monkeypatch.setattr('B.foo', classmethod(mock_b__foo))`.

Comment: @chepner , thanks, your solution works ok. Do you have any ideas regarding the second snippet ?

Comment: You have the right idea; `B` is defined and holds its own reference to the original class `A` before you get around to patching the *name* `A`.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner 's comment solves the issue with the first snippet, `monkeypatch.setattr` should be called with an instance of `classmethod` not `function` the code should be:

```
def test_B(monkeypatch):
  def mock_b__foo() -> str:
return 'bar'

monkeypatch.setattr('B.foo', classmethod(mock_b__foo))
```